# How to set indicator in the middle of TabBar linear unselected tabs?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, tabbar

How to show an indicator in the middle of the line under tabs as shown in picture? I have tried many ways but I only got the indicator upon line. I want it to be in middle of it as shown in the picture. I want to do it in native without packages.

[image: The image of the tabBar]

Answer (score 0):

After a while struggling with this I've found a solution and It's working good. Here's what I did:

```
Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 1),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffc4c4c4), width: 1.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TabBar(
                      isScrollable: true,
                      indicatorWeight: 3,
                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32, right: 32, bottom: 16, top: 24),
                      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                      indicatorColor: Color(0xff00C7D1),
                      labelColor: Color(0xff767899),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                      tabs: [
                        Text("A pagar"),
                        Text("Acordos"),
                        Text('Pagos'),
                        Text('Inativos'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

I hope flutter make It easier someday.